# Using ignorePlugin to ignore one folder from dependencies.

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

I've realized that one of a big folder inside one of my dependencies is not required. But since it takes almost 30kb of my build size, I wish to ignore it from the final webpack build. For that, i'm trying to use the `webpack ignorePlugin`.

This is what i've tried till now:

```
new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/precomputed$/, /elliptic$/),
```

The absolute path for the folder that I wanna ignore is :
`node_modules/elliptic/precomputed`

What i'm doing wrong here ? Is there anything else required ? Thanks for help ! Appreciate it :)

Comment: Try `new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/\/elliptic\/precomputed$/)`

Comment: Or just `new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^node_modules\/elliptic\/precomputed$/)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That didn't worked.

Answer (score 3):

The regular expressions you're using don't match the path of the module.

`/^\.\/precomputed$/` matches only exactly `./precomputed`. Because it's using the beginning of string `^` and the end of the string `$`, and in between is only `./precomputed`.

`/elliptic$/` matches every string that ends in `elliitic`.

The correct regular expression for your module would be:

```
/elliptic\/precomputed$/
```

But this matches only the modules that end in `elliptic/precomputed` (because of the `$` anchor). For instance `elliptic/precomputed.js` or `elliptic/precomputed/submodule` are not matched. If you intend to include these as well you can remove the `$` and it will match all of them:

```
/elliptic\/precomputed/
```

Try it in [Regexr](http://regexr.com/3fifl), when you add `$` to the pattern you'll see that only the first one matches.

Comment: There might be issue with my regex, but even then ignorePlugin isn't working as expected. The folder isn't ignored in the final build. :(